# Does Daredevil really only (mostly) take place in Hell's Kitchen?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil, daredevil-2015

Watching the Netflix show, it seems implied that everything more or less takes place in Hell's Kitchen (from the "Devil of Hell's Kitchen" name to the locations given here and then in terms of block and street number, to the blueprints we see in some episodes).

It makes sense, since Daredevil operates on foot almost all the time, and, well, it takes a while to even cross Manhattan.

Yet, we see Karen or other characters hail cabs; Stick uses a car (with a driver); the Russians mostly travel by car; and at the end of the first season, there is a pretty long sequence involving a FBI/Police convoy that lasts for a few minutes.

Now... Hell's Kitchen is roughly twenty by four blocks. It's small. If really the bulk of the show takes place in there, how can there be (a) that many gangs and criminals operating only in that area? (b) that much use of cars and trucks? (c) that much money for criminal to fight about, in real estate/drug/whatever?

I mean, really, it's... small.

[image: Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell%27s_Kitchen,_Manhattan)]]
*Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell%27s_Kitchen,_Manhattan).*

Comment: You'd be surprised - that's plenty of space and docks for more than two gangs to get crowded in.  That said, I looked at this map myself after Season 2, and mentally I nudged it out two avenues and a further 5 blocks north and south.  Technically that would cover Times Square and a tunnel, but I imagine it's close enough.

Comment: Well the MCU does have fictional countries and planets, so it's highly plausible that Hell's Kitchen is larger than it would be in real life.

Comment: But then, there is still some internal consistency issue - if it's bigger thwn in reality, Daredevil must basically walk or run across every time and cannot efficiently fight crime in time.

Comment: Well there is no indication that he fights crime all the time. That would be near impossible, but I get what you mean lol. Most likely, Daredevil is fighting crime one step at a time. Either that, or he's REALLY fast.

Answer (score 3):

Recall Rosalie Carbone to Luke Cage:

> You could kill me. That would be easy for you. But my Russian friends from Brighton Beach would have no qualms shooting up school yards and taking out whole families, Moscow style, if you did that. We make too much money together.

Brighton Beach is *far* from Hell’s Kitchen. The Russians are seen “mostly driving,” because in context of show where they are “coming to get Daredevil,” they must drive from their Brighton base to Hell’s Kitchen. That drive alone would make them hate Daredevil even more.

[image]

It gets worse for them, though: Fisk facilitates the Russians taking on Kitchen Cab, extending their taxi business into Hell’s Kitchen, a fact that increases their driving to, in, and around Hell’s Kitchen.

And it still gets even worse for them. After they effectively lost the war with the Kingpin, the Russian Mafia reorganized and resumed their criminal activities. They renewed their cooperation with Madame Gao and agreed to move the Steel Serpent exclusively, which covered most of the Hand's actives of Lower Manhattan and New Jersey.

The key point is that while Daredevil operates in Hell’s Kitchen, no one else of the show is so tightly bound, particularly the Russian mafia, the Kingpin and his operations, the police, the FBI, Madame Gao’s operations, et. al. But part of the conceit of the show involved a plot which sees most of these organizations coming to Hell’s Kitchen for various reasons seeking him out.